# How to remove the "white position circle" in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to remove this control in google map ? :
[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling this?

Comment: That control has been removed in the latest experimental version (unless you enable it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

These controls can be set to false

- Zoom control
- Rotate control
- Scale control
- Street View control
- Map Type control

initMap

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -33, lng: 151},
    zoomControl: false,
    scaleControl: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Even setting those 5 to false, the circle is still there ... I could use disableDefaultUI to true but I need to keep the zoom control ...